# Choosing a Column of the type TimeStamp to be a primary key in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dilemma choosing a primary key between a column which has the type TimeStamp and introducing a surrogate key which should be a identity column.
I have created a small app in which I use .NET SqlBulkCopy class in order to copy data from the source table to the destination table.
The app does not perform well when the primary key is a column of the type TimeStamp and do perform well when the primary key is an identity columns.
This statement is valid until the number of records I have to copy reach some magic number. After that both variants perform well.
I do not know what might be the reason of slow performance for a table with TimeStamp as a primary key?
Any ideas?

I have tried to find any kind of the additional resources about the type TIMESTAMP.
I have found just that the value should increase linearly, and the type occupies 8 bytes.
The type is deprecated ( or not it depends on the documentation ).

I would like to know a logical explanation why the app does not perform well when the PK is of the type TIMESTAMP.

Comment: `timestamp` in SQL Server, is a (deprecated) synonym for `rowversion`, a `binary(8)` value, and is *not* a primary key candidate (`rowversion` is *not* deprecated, only the synonym). There can easily be duplicate values. If you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` 2 or more rows at the same time, those 2 row *will* have the same `rowversion` value.

Comment: Well, I'm with @Larnu 100% on this, but one thing. If you mark the column using rowversion as unique, you won't get duplicate values. Oh, you'll get the occasional error as it tries to insert a duplicate value, but on retry from the client, it'll work when it generates a new value. Still a bad choice.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good point! But, what about slowlines of the app. Why in the case of the identity column as the primary key, the app works better then in the case of the timestamp column? TimeStamp should be linear or not?

Comment: @Martin, not sure about the performance since I've never used a `timestamp` as a primary key but it might simply be that stats needed to be updated.

Comment: For starters, generating identity values is optimized by the engine to reserve a block up front instead, as inserting identities is a much more common operation. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) explicitly call out `rowversion` as a bad choice for a primary key, primarily because it will change on any modification, whereas a primary key is supposed to remain unchanged if the row identity remains unchanged (violating this would break foreign keys, among other things). Performance is really the less interesting bit here.

Comment: Note also that `rowversion` increases monotonically, but only within the entire database, not a single table. If you're doing this in a database where other transactions are happening, your `rowversion` columns will not have contiguous values.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman! That could be a logical explanation. I have monitored page splitting and did not see any difference.  For example when I have to insert 500 records in the case of the identity column the app was finished for about 10 seconds. In other case when timestamp is used more then 200 seconds.

Comment: I would, honestly, expect performance (over time) to be worse on a `timestamp`/`rowversion` Primary Key, @Martin . If the PK is clustered it's most certainly going to become fragmented when the index has to be *completely* rewritten when you update a value in a column, and a row that was near the start of the index needs to be moved to the end.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu this is also a good argument!